# How to filter out the string inside brackets from a column and create it as a separate column in SQL

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a table called Driver. The table has one column and is as follows

```
        Driver
Alex Hendry(2012815381)
Sam Adams(2524789897)
Pedro Sanchez(6528719365)
```

I want to create a separate column called DriverID which has the values in the bracket as follows

```
      Driver                        DriverID
Alex Hendry(2012815381)            2012815381
Sam Adams(2524789897)              2524789897
Pedro Sanchez(6528719365)          6528719365
```

Previously, I was using Excel to create the Driver ID column. The formula I used was =MID(B5,SEARCH("(",B5)+1,SEARCH(")",B5)-SEARCH("(",B5)-1)+0

How can I create the same column in sql?

```
Select DRIVER, 
       ()  as DriverID
       from driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your table name is DriverTable:

```
SELECT
    xQ.Driver,
    SUBSTRING(xQ.Driver,xQ.StartIndex+1,xQ.EndIndex-xQ.StartIndex-1) AS DriverId

FROM 
(SELECT 
    Driver,
    PATINDEX('%(%',Driver) AS StartIndex,
    PATINDEX('%)%',Driver) AS EndIndex
FROM DriverTable) AS xQ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql; create table dispatch02 as select 
t1.Driver,  
      scan(SCAN(t1.Driver,2,'('),1,')') AS DriverId
FROM work.TESTACCESS AS t1;
```

This worked perfectly for me